# MongoDB Database on Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I figured I'd make this new personal project with MongoDB, after all seems pretty easy. And in fact, it was pretty painless, except it won't connect to the right Database, and I don't know why.

[This what Compass looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J6uX.png)

So I want it to connect to the 'doteco' database. And it just won't, it keeps going to that 'test' database.

I've tried both

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=doteco
```

and

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/doteco
```

But it refuses, it only connects to Test. The program doesn't have any manual connecting to it, it's just the URI on the properties and that's it. It just creates a the collection `words` under Test and keeps populating it.

Edit-

Some of the code, it's so simple it's a case of 'I don't know why this is going wrong.'

The Entity/Document

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document("words")
public class WordDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String word;
    private Integer numberOfLetters;
    private Integer flag;
}
```

The Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface WordRepository extends MongoRepository<WordDocument, String> {

    @Query("{word:'?0'}")
    Optional<WordDocument> findByWord(String word);
}
```

The properties is the ones I've shown earlier, and just manually creating the object to test.

```java
@Override
    public void save() {
        WordDocument word = new WordDocument();
        word.setWord("Word");
        word.setFlag(1);
        word.setNumberOfLetters(7);
        WordDocument save = wordRepository.insert(word);
        System.out.println(save);
    }
```

And it's just a regular run, there are no configuration classes, no extra beans, no nothing.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class DotecoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DotecoApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I want it to save on the doteco database, not on the 'test' one. I had a Database Test using the Intellij Ultimate Database feature on, thought might be the case, but persists even when I turn it off, or use the regular Intellij Community. Maybe it just THINKS it belongs there for some reason now?

Comment: Share some code for your personal project. Wondering why `words` collection is created and populated.

Comment: I've added some(most) of the code.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code or configuration. Just setting `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/doteco` in the `application.properties` file should work. I have multiple projects doing that. Springboot does not use the config from intellij IDEA.

Comment: @Bala Yes, that is what I thought, but for some reason it only connects to the Test database, figured there might be something I'm missing? Not like it's unworkable, but it's a bit messy, and weird.